# Does prayer done to non-hindu gods also leads to Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, non-hindu

It is being said that whosoever god one prays, in the end the prayer leads to Vishnu.

I think there is a sloka in which it is said that just like all waters in the world flows towards sea. All prayers done to any god in the end reaches Vishnu.

आकाशात् पतितं तोयं यथा गच्छति सागरम्

सर्व देव नमस्कारः केशवं प्रतिगच्छति

Krishna too when showed his Virat roop, all gods were seen inside of him.

But what happens when a non-hindu, non-vedic person prays to his own god.
Does it also reach Vishnu ?

An important point to be noted is, in no country/religion in the world god has taken birth or has been seen.
As far as I know in no historical record present in anywhere in the world, god is seen or has taken birth.
Only in hinduism/Aryavrata ,god himself has taken birth on earth.
So, I am not sure to which god non-hindus prays to.
(Please correct me if I am wrong. I respect other religions. But to my knowledge god has taken avatar only in Aryavrata)

Comment: No, prayers done to deities or Gods in other religions won't lead to Vishnu

Comment: @ArtistFormerlyKnownAsCSD what if they were ancestors of those people like buddha etc. Shrimad bhagvat gita mentions worship of ancestors

Answer (score 1):

The word specifically used is देव, Devas exist according to Veda and other scriptures.

Does Allah exist? Or Yahweh? (in the form of their interaction with jesus/mohammed and humans)? **Definitely not**

They're imaginary.

> Krishna too when showed his Virat roop, all gods were seen inside of him.

Use the term Deva instead of 'gods', and it will help you a lot. No gods were inside him, as there's only one god which is Ishvara, and not Allah or Yahweh. All Devas are inside Ishvara, though.

Prayers to Devas like Surya or Maarut or Indra goes to Ishvara, but those to imaginary creatures won't go anywhere, since you're praying to your imagination/delusions and not to an actual thing that exists.

---

There's a secondary meaning to this specific verse however, that I believe you, and most people are missing.

> सर्व देव नमस्कारः केशवं प्रतिगच्छति

The key words are keshava and namsakaara. Ka क means the body or Aatma and Isha, you know already, hopefully. Va is the Aapa Bija denoting pervaded-ness.

Therefore, Keshava is the lord (isha) that pervades (va) the individual aatma/body (ka).

In namaskaara, the key part is nama नम na means "not" and ma means "me". Namaskaara is the kaara or action of 'not me-ing-ness'.

The primary use of nama is in mantra nyaasa where everything ends with namah for eg: सूर्याय अङ्गुष्ठाभ्यां नमः (to Surya in my thumb, not me) or मुखे भास्कराय नमः (to Bhaaskara within my face, not me) etc.

So, the secondary (or rather, the better) meaning is that all mantra nyaasas that include namah result in the residence of keshava or Ishvara, even if the residence is given to Surya or others.

If you know some things in depth, then, if we were to pick one of these meanings, this meaning is more suitable than the prayer/worship leading to Ishvara via all Devataas.

In which case, your question is flawed, and prayers to Ishvara don't get there by any other means than direct prayer to Ishvara, which is done only via the use of Pranava. Although, the Vishnu cult/sect people would also assert this can be done via Puja to the form(s) of Vishnu... Anyways, that's wrong because Vishnu (Ishvara and not the one of the 12 Aadityas) doesn't exist in the form of any murti. You can use the murti as a more graspable/gross means to address Pranava, but without Pranava, no prayer (to Ishvara) will ever receive fruition.

---

On a side note, this is also why all Avataaras (of Ishavara) take birth in the land that they do it in. Because, only via the means of Pranava is Ishvara invoked and prayed to. Via means of the karma of that prayer, after the invocation, is the eventual fruition of divine descent (avatarana) achieved. Since no one else uses Pranava, it cannot happen in any other area. The Buddhits fail as they use it to meditate primarily, rather than praying **to** Pranava directly. Ishvara simply has a higher chance to descend in populated authentic Hindu locations (Southern Nepal, UP, Bihar),the main regions were Punjab/Haryana/Utaarakhand etc in earlier times, as we can observe, due to the prevalence of the understanding, invocation and prayer to Pranava. These are the locations where Ishvara, fully (Krishna/Raama,etc) or partially (Veda Vyaasa etc) descend, as the prayer karma of these places is the maximum by those who pray to Pranava (Ishvara). Although, nowadays that is going to the ditch as well.

If all authentic and well read and learned Hindus moved to a small Island, and prayed (the exact same prayer) every day, with bhaava, for hours to Pravana, I can guarantee that Island would produce a partial (if not complete) Avataara of Ishvara within a few years, despite being on the opposite side of 'Aryavarta'. This applies to all other Devas as well, but in that case, you don't pray to Pranava, but rather to the Deva.

The Christian or Islamic prayer doesn't produce divine descent of Ishvara because they're not invoking the Vaachaka of Ishavara (Pranava), they say Amen/Ameen instead of Pranava, which is probably a bastardization of the shabda. They're praying to an imaginary creature using a bastardized address (Amen/Ameen) and they're getting imaginary results. Their societies have worked and do work, even now on Purushartha alone and not a bit of Daiva. They're failing in the Ishvara area on one hand, and, because they reject 'paganism' or rather, the existence of Devas, they're failing on easy to access help as well.

Anyways, that's swaying from the question, hope that answers everything.

Comment: Using the term Deva instead of 'Gods', will also help readers raised in different cultures from not getting too much confused, especially when "god" is used in the singular form.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Yeah true, unfortunately many people are confused regarding the meaning of "God" in English as they haven't been raised in the West. They assume that "gods" can be used to referred to any divine entity. Well it can, but very view people use it that way. Angel is far more suitable for Deva, if anything. Anyways, use of Sanskrit terms is always better than the mangled result of non translatable translations :)

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar if one's ancestors are buddha , Jesus or her mother, mahaveer ,any sikh guru or anyone who existed they worship them and gita mentions worship of ancestors. Those who worship ancestors, go to  ancestors. So can my point be considered like there is a chance that it may go to vishnu

Comment: And even for the Abrahamic religions, the etymology of "god" has a germanic origin sometimes said to refer to some minor deity in germanic pagan pantheon. Words do confuse, sometimes.

Comment: @GyroGearloose amusingly, God refers to 'that which is invoked'. It's traced from the Sanskrit हुत Huta (invoked in the fire), referring to Indra, primarily, and it eventually turns into Guð in old norse, Gott in German and so on all the way to God. The linguists like to add the part about proto indo european as always though, but anyways, technically, the correct gods are the Devas haha.

Comment: @Hope They will go to the Pitrs not to Ishvara (Vishnu).  The last 'thought' (motivated by karma) you have at the time of death is what causes your next rebirth. The thing you worship (extremely sincerely) is likely to be your last thought. If you think about Pitrs, you will go to Pitr Loka. Ishvara isn't really related to it. That's assuming that your ancestors are in Pitr loka though. As for worship, it won't get to Ishvara either, that doesn't fit in either context of the verse OP has provided, as Devas are special for a Manvantara, whereas Pitrs are just temporarily elevated humans.

Comment: I was saying can prayer go to shri hari @DushyantShreyaskar

Comment: @Hope He's worshiping the Aaditya Aryamaa aka second form of Surya. The worship **technically** reaches Ishvara, as everything you see in this world, including your body and mind are made OUT OF Ishvara. The world to Ishvara, is like the web to a spider. The spider makes the web FROM ITSELF. The worship *indirectly* reaches Ishvara, is a suitable position imo, as the being of Devas has a higher amount of divine-ness (paramatmaamsha) borrowed from Ishvara. Certainly, all of the worship doesn't directly reach Ishvara. Will you be born next to Vishnu? No, Surya Loka in Svarga is far more likely.

Comment: @Hope >I was saying can prayer go to shri hari.

Not in the case of Pitrs, but in the case of Devas, the prayer does indirectly reach Ishvara (Hari/Vishnu). Ignoring the technical realities of Ishvara being the prayer, Ishvara doing the prayer, and Ishvara being prayed to, as everything is Ishvara.

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar But What about gods of other pagan religion eg- Ancient Greek Religion also have some devtas like Zeus. Are they real ? Have they taken birth or Is there any record of them being seen by people ?

Comment: @river Without going in the reasoning, as long as the prayer utilizes a ritual, it still reaches the associated deity that actually exists. Even if Zeus or Poseidon don't exist, someone controlling the water and thunder does (varuna and indra), so the prayer reaches the concerned entities ONLY if it utilizes a ritual. The ritual must also contain associations with the actual deity (indra/varuna). Eg: The number 9, head and fire is associated with mars and relevant deities (Ares). Prayer without ritual, in your bedroom won't achieve anything if referring to a non existent deity, though.